# Update all related records when a record is updated

Tags: trigger

Use Case: If I update a Agreement record ,then all the related Agreements to be updated with Termination Date on Parent agreement record.

On Agreement we have Relationship from and Relationship To Related list. This is nothing but Related agreement records and these are Related Agreement object. Where we have Relationship from and Relationship To Lookup fields. Relationship from is the parent agreement record and Relationship To is child Agreement Record.

If Update Parent agreement(Relationship from) then on Relationship To agreement(child agreement) should be updated with same Termination date field value on Parent.

I have this trigger  am getting records for Related Agreement record. But line no 11 gives null value for Termination Date.

Class:

```
public class TerminationDate {

   public static Boolean isFirstTime = true;
   }
```

This is the  trigger . Related agreement query returning records but @11 getting null value for Termination Date.

```
    if(TerminationDate.isFirstTime){
        TerminationDate.isFirstTime = false;

        Map<Id,Date> acc = new Map<Id,Date>();
        for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c a:Trigger.New)    {
    if(a.Apttus__Status_Category__c=='Terminated') {
        Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ar=new Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c();
        acc.put(a.id,ar.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c);
        system.debug(acc);
    }
}


 List<Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c> relagrmt=[select id,Name,Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.id,Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.Name from Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c where Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c in: acc.keyset()];

        for(Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ag:relagrmt){

          ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c=acc.get(ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id);
            update ag;
            system.debug(ag);
              }    

}

}
```

Comment: I am assuming line 6 is the first query and it seems redundant. The records that you are looking for are already in Trigger new and just need filtering. It may happen that there are no records matching the criteria. And I am note where you are using those afterwards

Comment: You must query relationship fields used in trigger context. This is a very common issue and I've linked a post that explains the problem above.

Comment: As a side note, the use of static Booleans as trigger recursion guards is a very bad pattern and will likely cause you problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Your query assumes that trigger.new contains records where Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'Terminated' - I would question if that's actually the case in your test runs. If it's not the query will return 0 records. Aside from that, a better code structure would be to hold off on performing queries until you've first looped through trigger.new in order to identify relevant records, e.g. check first to see if records are terminated, then you can grab the IDs, then assuming you have at least one record ID that meets this criteria, perform your queries from there. Otherwise you will be making queries against every insert and update of this object (and you only have so many queries per transaction). Also I'd recommend removing the first query as you already have the record in trigger.new

On your related agreement query, it seems odd that your query requires the same ID value be in two different fields, Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.id & Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id (which BTW I would write as just Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__c and Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c since this returns the ID value). Does Apttus really reference the parent ID in two fields? That seems redundant and I would question if that's really the case. If you are are attempting to get records on a related list from the main agreement, you only need a match on one lookup field, since a single lookup field is the essence of that relationship. You'll need to do some checking to find what the relationship field behind that list of interest is called in the API.

It seems most of your functional issues are related to properly understanding the data structure more than the code itself.

Comment: @ Brig larmier,Thanks for your update. Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c is the parent Agreement and Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__c is the child agreement. If we create new Agreement, the child records will getting created under Related Agreement Related list on Agreement. If Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c (Parent record is updated) ,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__c (child record) needs to be updated.

Comment: I have modified my trigger

Comment: I can spot a few issues: 1) You are putting ar.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c in your map which would be null since ar is a new record you just created. I am assuming you mean to add a.[termdate] here? 2) You cannot set ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c as this is not a field on the ag record. I would think you are meaning to set ag.[termdate] here? 3) You shouldn't call "update ag" in a loop, but instead should add updated records to a list, then update that list after the loop completes (again, apex limits)

Comment: Other than that you are shaping up to be on the right track. I would suggest you read about a few key apex best practices we've touched on here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices (particularly practice #2). This is also a FANTASTIC article that really helped me when starting in apex: https://www.iterativelogic.com/salesforce-apex-trigger-best-practices/

Comment: One more thing: after your Trigger.New loop completes, you should check if (!acc.isEmpty()) before moving on to the rest of your logic. Otherwise you will deplete a query call on an empty query (and in other cases potentially spend some apex CPU run time / other limits on a dead end). This is a very common practice after your first loop completes for the sake of code efficiency. Here's a reference on apex limits to keep bookmarked: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm